# Firebase App Check Unverified Requests Java Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-app-check

Hi im struggling to get verified requests from app check, this is my code called on OnStart

```
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
    FirebaseAppCheck firebaseAppCheck = FirebaseAppCheck.getInstance();
    firebaseAppCheck.installAppCheckProviderFactory(PlayIntegrityAppCheckProviderFactory.getInstance());


    startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, NextActivity.class));
    finish();


}
```

it works fine with debug AppcheckProviderFactory but when I publish it on Google Play it won't work. I double checked firebase project linked to play console, i correctly put app signing sha 256 key from play console then downloaded google service . json .

these are the logs,

2023-04-10 11:53:29.019   943-1283  PlayCore                com.sidd29.hellodost                 I  UID: [10964]  PID: [943] IntegrityService : requestIntegrityToken(IntegrityTokenRequest{nonce=ARDLlMSdMYm4hDPBl_y6XXUF9imQvxxPchUzVyKYETnOg92RcM0c7IU_0Oyto2Up-FDH-qNcIwsSZPNQIdqtER1lLRdwpYZfFyQMum-ZA5SKycO4oKu4eo3ZrGM2g_VoNF5Ir4hqJOSjzYBzWo_Iyi3fQNGKxZSsUpwF4i_MBohM, cloudProjectNumber=638805104947})

2023-04-10 11:53:29.022   943-1284  PlayCore                com.sidd29.hellodost                 I  UID: [10964]  PID: [943] IntegrityService : Initiate binding to the service.

2023-04-10 11:53:29.036   943-943   PlayCore                com.sidd29.hellodost                 I  UID: [10964]  PID: [943] IntegrityService : ServiceConnectionImpl.onServiceConnected(ComponentInfo{com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.integrityservice.IntegrityService})

2023-04-10 11:53:29.038   943-1284  PlayCore                com.sidd29.hellodost                 I  UID: [10964]  PID: [943] IntegrityService : linkToDeath

i also double checked the current google cloud console project selected is the same as firebase in google play console/ AppIntigrity. What's wrong with my code or with firebase , how to fix it?